# How to get Ubuntu standard background settings dialogue back?

Tags: unity, system-settings, appearance, gnome-control-center

After installing the gnome shell in Ubuntu 13.10 the dialogue for changing the desktop wallpaper gets replaced with gnomes's dialogue, which is feature less, poor and useless thing. To illustrate the difference of both dialogues: This is how it looks like, before you install the gnome packages (and what I want to get back):

[image]

This is how it looks like after you installed the gnome packages:

[image]

Does anybody know how to get the Unity version of the "Change Background" dialogue back?

Comment: How did you installed Gnome Shell? Via ppa?

What happens when you run `gnome-control-center background` in terminal?

Comment: @kubahaha I found out about the cause of the problem and answered my own question...

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with GNOME sessions other than Unity. The"Change Background" dialogue is only shown, if you have Unity enabled, because Ubuntu uses some patching to enable that option.

If you use any other shell like Gnome shell or (like me) Cairo-dock, which use standard gnome-session, You have to suffer this ridiculous Gnome choice. Standard Gnome sessions doesn't permit you to select a custom picture as background, if it isn't in the root of `/home/user/Pictures`. God gracious, give us peace from those Gnome designers!